# How to add Nickname in Contact Entry?

Tags: c#, google-contacts-api

I want to add "Nickname" in Google Contact using  "Google.GData.Extensions.Apps" .

I am able to create Nickname as:

NicknameElement obj_nickname   = new NicknameElement();
obj_nickname.Name              = " Jenifer";

But how to add i to Contact Entry?

Answer (score 1):

The Contacts API does support nicknames using the gContact:nickname element.  This element is new in version 3.0 of the Contacts API, and as such is in the gContact namespace.  For example:

```
<atom:entry xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
    xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'>
  <atom:category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind'
      term='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact' />
  <gd:name>
    <gd:givenName>Victor</gd:givenName>
    <gd:familyName>Fryzel</gd:familyName>
    <gd:fullName>Vic Fryzel</gd:fullName>
  </gd:name>

  <!-- ... -->

  <gContact:nickname>Vic</gContact:nickname>
</atom:entry>
```

Fortunately, the .NET client library has been updated with a getter and setter for this parameter, although the methods are undocumented in the [.NET Developer's Guide](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html).  But, you can find them in [the source code](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/src/gcontacts/contactentry.cs#654).They're in the source code here:

Thus, you can use the following code to set a contact's nickname.

```
Contact newContact = new Contact();
newContact.Title.Text = "Victor Fryzel";
newContact.Nickname = new Nickname("Vic");
// ...
// This example assumes the ContactRequest object (cr) is already set up.
Contact createdContact = cr.Insert(newContact);
```

For more information, please see the [.NET Developer's Guide](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html).  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To further help others,

Using the latest .net API, I needed to set the nickname slightly differently as I couldn't find the Nickname object. I'll keep it similar to Vic's answer as to extend not replace it. This approach has been tested and works for me. Sorry Vic if I've missed something with your solution, I can't add comments yet.

```
Contact newContact = new Contact();
newContact.Title.Text = "Victor Fryzel";
newContact.ContactEntry.Nickname = "nicknameString";
// ...
// This example assumes the ContactRequest object (cr) is already set up.
Contact createdContact = cr.Insert(newContact);
```

Included namespaces as per documentation.

```
using Google.Contacts;
using Google.GData.Contacts;
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Extensions;
```